# I need help to cancel my Hard drive partition

Tags: external-hard-drive

My hard drive is partitioned  into two let say ( ***drive G and drive H***) and I have files on both. I will like to cancel the partition and have the hard drive as one. Will I lose the documents or files on any of the the drives after canceling the partition and putting the drive together?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "cancel your HDD partition"?

Answer (score 1):

Even a HDD with a single partition is still “partitioned”.

Basically, you want to merge the two partitions. That is, however, not possible. Instead, you need to do the following:

1. Move files away from second partition
2. Delete second partition
3. Enlarge first partition so it covers the entire disk

If the data on the second partition fits in the free space on the first partition, you’re all good. Just move them there and continue with step 2. If the data is too large, you need to find some other temporary location.

If you absolutely cannot provide enough temporary space, you need to repeat the following (super high risk) steps until the second partition is empty:

1. Defragment second partition
2. Shrink second partition as much as possible
3. Move second partition to the end of the disk as much as possible
4. Extend first partition as much as possible
5. Move files from second to first partition until you run out of space on first partition
6. If files are remaining on second partition, GOTO step 1

To move partitions, you need a third-party partition manager. It’s also a very time-consuming operation.

Answer (score -1):

How about using [partition wizard](http://www.partitionwizard.com/)

. It is good and you can merge the partitions using this [guide](http://www.partitionwizard.com/).
If there is any problem or suggestion please comment once.

Comment: The website you link to isn't actually a guide.  How about you put the guide in your answer, so its helpful, instead of just a bunch of links?